# Error linking libwebrtc.a with C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, webrtc, linker-errors, ninja

I have built webrtc for linux and getting `libwebrtc.a` using

```
gn gen out/Default --args=is_debug=false rtc_use_h264=true target_cpu="x64" target_os="linux" clang_use_chrome_plugins=false use_ghash=false symbol_level=2 use_custom_libcxx=false is_component_ffmpeg=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" rtc_include_tests=false rtc_build_examples=true rtc_build_tools=false use_rtti=true rtc_enable_protobuf=false rtc_use_h264=true rtc_link_pipewire=true proprietary_codecs=true
```

and

```
ninja -C . webrtc \
peerconnection_client
```

but when I am trying to link the static webrtc with my c++ project I am getting following 4 linker errors:

```
1. test.cpp:(.text._ZN10H264BypassedEncoderC2ERKN7cricket10VideoCodecERNS_14DCVAgentClientE+0x191):
    undefined reference to   
    `absl::EqualsIgnoreCase(std::basic_string_view<char,   
    std::char_traits<char> >, std::basic_string_view<char,   
    std::char_traits<char> >)'
 2. CMakeFiles/webRTCserver.dir/src/audio/testEncoder.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN10testEncoderE[_ZTVN10testEncoderE]+0xb8):
    undefined reference to
    `webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int,
    std::optional<long>)'
 3. testDecoderFactory.cpp/testEncoderFactory.cpp:(.text._ZN10testEncoderFactory20GetSupportedEncodersEv+0x20b): undefined reference to
    `webrtc::SdpAudioFormat::SdpAudioFormat(std::basic_string_view<char,
    std::char_traits<char> >, int, unsigned long,
    std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
    std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
    std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
    std::allocator<char> > >,
    std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const,
    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
    std::allocator<char> > > > >&&)'
 4. H264BypassedEncoder.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN10H264BypassedEncoderE[_ZTVN10H264BypassedEncoderE]+0x20):
    undefined reference to
    `webrtc::VideoEncoder::SetFecControllerOverride(webrtc::FecControllerOverride*)'
```

When I look for symbols in libwebrtc.a like error 2 as shown below:

```
nm --demangle libwebrtc.a | grep -i webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth
```

I get the following output:

```
0000000000000000 T webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
                 U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
```

Now I am not sure why nm shows the output the way it does. But then using `ar -d libwebrtc.a <*.o>` I removed all the files which has

```
U webrtc::AudioEncoder::OnReceivedUplinkBandwidth(int, absl::optional<long>)
```

I am still getting the linker errors.

Same thing is with other undefined reference errors other than `webrtc::VideoEncoder::SetFecControllerOverride` which I am not sure which target will provide.

**Questions:**

- Could someone tell me other way to debug errors 1,2 and 3 as the
  symbols are there in libwebrtc.a
- What could be the reason that linker error 1 and 3 refer to .cpp file
  opposed to .o file as in error 2
- how to find ninja target for webrtc build to resolve error 4's undefined reference?

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the comment to try using is_clang=false, I did the same and got the following error while building libwebrtc.a file:

```
[5/2977] CXX obj/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api/sctp_transport_interface.o
FAILED: obj/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api/sctp_transport_interface.o 
g++ -MMD -MF obj/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api/sctp_transport_interface.o.d -DUSE_UDEV -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS_CERTS=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DFULL_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_CSD -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_LOCAL -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DCR_SYSROOT_HASH=e7c53f04bd88d29d075bfd1f62b073aeb69cbe09 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -DWEBRTC_ENABLE_PROTOBUF=0 -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_INTERNAL_AUDIO_DEVICE -DRTC_ENABLE_VP9 -DHAVE_SCTP -DWEBRTC_USE_H264 -DWEBRTC_LIBRARY_IMPL -DWEBRTC_NON_STATIC_TRACE_EVENT_HANDLERS=0 -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DABSL_ALLOCATOR_NOTHROW=1 -I../.. -Igen -I../../third_party/abseil-cpp -fno-strict-aliasing --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fPIC -pipe -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -pthread -m64 -march=x86-64 -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__= -D__TIME__= -D__TIMESTAMP__= -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-comments -Wno-packed-not-aligned -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=gnu++11 -Wno-narrowing -Wno-class-memaccess -fno-exceptions --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_sid_amd64-sysroot -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -c ../../api/sctp_transport_interface.cc -o obj/api/libjingle_peerconnection_api/sctp_transport_interface.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/utility:68:0,
                 from ../../api/sctp_transport_interface.cc:11:
/usr/include/c++/7/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h:3:10: fatal error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/wordsize.h>
```

Comment: Is `std::optional<long>` the same as `absl::optional<long>`?  https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/abseil_cpp/html/classabsl_1_1optional.html

Comment: @stark I am not sure.

Comment: @YugSingh are you using clang? I also suggest to do a `strings` on the lib to see the mangled names, there could be different in the lib and in your test programs for some reason.

Comment: @Manuel I am building my test program using g++

Comment: @YugSingh I've seen compatibility problems and be solved with `is_clang=false` in `gn gen out/release --args=` but I don't know if that affects `g++`.

Comment: @Manuel on setting `is_clang=false` I started getting compilation errors while building `libwebrtc.a` using `ninja -C .` : `fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory`
**I have added the complete error under Edit in the question**

Comment: @YugSingh hm, I wasn't sure it affected `g++`. The only thing I can think of is it can't find the `.a` lib or it is linking something (another lib) in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix all the issues related to linking built `libwebrtc.a` and the built executable works.

***Could someone tell me other way to debug errors 1,2 and 3 as the symbols are there in libwebrtc.a***

> Was using `cxx_std_17` and the required was `cxx_std_14`
>
> The issue lies in usage of `cxx_std_17`. In the code that I was building
> has used certain methods which were not available with default
> `cxx_std_11` so I just used `cxx_std_17` but it caused a lot of issues
> with `libwebrtc.a`. Even though [webrtc style guide](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/HEAD/style-guide.md#c_version) says that the
> code is **valid c++17** but faced issues.  In the same style guide it's
> mentioned that webrtc code is written is c++14 and that gave me idea to
> switch to `cxx_std_14` and the errors resolved. As mentioned in same [webrtc style
> guide](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/HEAD/style-guide.md#general-advice) that "Some older parts of the code violate the style guide
> in various ways." so I think some older code is there which caused the
> errors

***What could be the reason that linker error 1 and 3 refer to .cpp file opposed to .o file as in error 2***

> I think the reason behind .cpp or .o is that if error originated in my code then it shows .cpp but if it's in 3rd party library, as was the case with a few linker errors which originated from libwebrtc.a, then it shows the error in .o file as the library only has compiled files

***how to find ninja target for webrtc build to resolve error 4's undefined reference?***

> Issue was with the commit I was trying to build.
>
> From [webrtc release notes](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/b1tdwrXKuHI/m/OH7oSL7OBwAJ) I found out the stable [m77 branch head
> commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+log/branch-heads/m77) and found out the commit I was using didn't have the
> functions the linker error was referring to but the head commit of stable m77
> branch have those functions.

**NOTE:**
In general to get the target which has the .o file with the required symbol we just need to do `grep` and it will list out where the symbol related function is defined and `ninja -t targets all` will display all the targets. So just go to corresponding `.ninja` file and copy all the `.o` files to the `webrtc.ninja` and build the `libwebrtc.a` again.